# Weird data format from firestore db

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

My data from Firestore looks this way:

`Timestamp(seconds=1566840930, nanoseconds=491000000)`

Since it's not a valid unix timestamp i have no idea on how to display it in a readable name, like dd.mm.yy.

I'm fetching data in a component:

```
@Component({
  firestore() {
    return {
      linksArray: db.collection('links')
    }
  }
})
```

Then using `v-for` i'm displaying a list of links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is a [Firestore `Timestamp` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp), which is defined as:

> A Timestamp represents a point in time independent of any time zone or calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at **nanosecond resolution** in UTC Epoch time.

So (like UNIX timestamps) it represents a point in time relative to the UTC Epoch time, but (unlike UNIX timestamps) it represents this time with nanosecond resolution.

If you want to get the millisecond resolution that UNIX timestamps are in, call [`toMillis()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#to-millis) on the `Timestamp`.